# Медленная работа микросервисов в Docker

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, tomee

Столкнулся с проблемой медленной работы приложения из трёх сервисов в контейнере докере. Разница в скорости работы c аналогичным приложением развёрнутым на хост-машине в 1.5 -3 раза.

OS Ubuntu 18

Сервисы могут отправлять друг другу HTTP запросы по схеме:

1. app2 к app1
2. app2 к app1 и app2

База данных MySQL расположена на хост-машине вне докера.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  app1:
    container_name: app1
    image: company/app1:latest
    volumes:
    - ./volumes/tomee/logs/app1:/usr/local/tomee/logs:cached
    network_mode: "host"


  app2:
    container_name: app2
    image: company/app2:latest
    depends_on:
      - app1
    volumes:
    - ./volumes/tomee/logs/app2:/usr/local/tomee/logs:cached
    network_mode: "host"


  app3:
    container_name: app3
    image: company/app3:latest
    depends_on:
    - app1
    - app2
    volumes:
    - ./volumes/tomee/logs/app3:/usr/local/tomee/logs:cached
    network_mode: "host"
```

Dockerfile для трёх сервисов выглядит одинаково:

```
FROM tomee:8-jre-7.0.5-plume
    
COPY ./conf/service.conf /usr/local/tomee/conf/service.conf
COPY ./conf/tomee.xml /usr/local/tomee/conf/tomee.xml
COPY ./conf/server.xml /usr/local/tomee/conf/server.xml
COPY ./conf/catalina.properties /usr/local/tomee/conf/catalina.properties
COPY app.war /usr/local/tomee/webapps
```

Comment: В докере, действительно, могут быть задержки. Но у Вас они феноменальные. Как диагностируете проблему? Я слышал про 30% максимум

Comment: `./volumes/tomee/logs/app3:...:cached` -- это в какую ос/фс?

Comment: @hedgehogues В app3 есть API с продолжительным временем выполнения. На хост-машине оно состовляет 5 секунд. В контейнере около 15 +/- 2 секунды. Диагностировал вызовом API несколько раз.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov если я правильно понял, то в обе стороны https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#cached

Comment: a без вольюмов тоже тормозит? на винде такой проброс работает раз в 50 медленней именованого вольюма ... или может какая виртуализация у проца не включена

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov без вольюмов тоже тормозит.

Comment: т. е. у вас разница в 3 раза на **одном** ноутбуке, на разных ОС?

Comment: А в чем причина такой долгой работы api на хост машине, какой ресурс наиболее потребляемый, диск, cpu, память ?